# Is it possible to change nautalis sidebar links?

Tags: nautilus

Nautalis has some unremovable default links in the sidebar for Desktop, Videos, Pictures, etc. I recently changed my home folder names to lowercase, and updated the `userdirs.dir` file to reflect this. Because of this the links in the sidebar are broken, and I would like to remove them or at least change them to reflect the new path. Is this possible to do without editing the source and compiling a custom version?

Comment: Until a better solution turns up, you could create soft links, eg `Pictures -> pictures`.